# Swift - self in deinit method

Tags: swift

Is it good practice to use self in swift deinit method?.
In objective C we avoid use of self in init and dealloc method.
Is same applied for swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 90% of cases *you have* to use `self` in `deinit`. Both in Swift and Objective-C.

That's actually the whole point of that method - the last chance to access that object before deallocation.

What you should avoid is storing `self` to another object from `deinit`, not accessing `self`.

Also, in Objective-C some people try to avoid using property setters and getters in `init` and `dealloc` to avoid dangerous side-effects that might be hidden in them, and they are accessing ivars directly instead (`_prop = nil` instead of `self.prop = nil`). That's actually impossible in Swift because there are no ivars. However, Swift is much safer in that regard. Note that `_prop = nil` in Objective-C still accesses `self`. It's just a short syntax for `self->_prop = nil`. We are avoiding properties, not `self`.